# Is it possible to access individual ag-grid column headers to implement: on-mouseover="method_name()" on them?

Tags: angular, html, css, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in my project to implement tools that are built in different Excell files in one comprehensive dynamic web-application.
The Excel feature that I am trying to implement now is this:
When I hover my mouse above the column header, a notice-shows-up describing the column use as you may see in the following link:

[image]

I have searched in the ag-grid documentation for a way to access individual ag-grid column headers html elements so that I may bind each one to the listener.
However, I couldn't find a solution.
This is the component html file. As you see it's very basic. I have added the on-mouseover listener, just for the sake of testing it.

```
<ag-grid-angular
style="width: 3000px ; height: 1000px;"
class="ag-theme-balham"
[rowData]="rowData"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs"
pagination
(cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
on-mouseover="over()"
>
```

And this is the relevant typescript code:

```
columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: 'Rattachement',
      field: 'rattachement',
      editable: true,
      cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
      cellEditorParams: {
        values: ['Audit', 'RA', 'Consulting', 'FA', 'Tax&Legal', 'ICS', 'Taj'],
      },
```

Obviously, any "mouse move" above the grid executes the over() method.
And what I want is: 
When a the mouse hovers above a CERTAIN column header, I execute the over() method depending on the column header ID.
I hope I was clear.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't see how adding a title attribute to the header would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going in wrong direction. No need to handle events like `mousemove`, `mouseover`.

You should actually use [`headerTooltip`](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/entities/colDef.d.ts#L36) property of `ColDef` for this.

So, your `ColDef` would be like this

```
{
  headerName: 'Rattachement',
  headerTooltip: 'whatever you like to show',  // <=
  field: 'rattachement',
  editable: true,
  cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
  cellEditorParams: {
    values: ['Audit', 'RA', 'Consulting', 'FA', 'Tax&Legal', 'ICS', 'Taj']
  }
}
```